# ¿Cómo puedo evitar sobrescribir datos en recursividad?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, recursión, guardar

Estoy desarrollando un programa que utiliza recursividad para completar una matriz de un juego de la cual, las filas, columnas y diagonal inferior deben sumar 24 (cuadrado mágico con agujeros).

El programa soluciona las filas, columnas y a diagonal cuando puede y si ya ha finalizado pero quedan huecos por rellenar, pone un número de los restantes en una posición libre y llama de nuevo a la función para intentar completar la matriz.
Si consigue que los números sumen 24 en todas las posiciones devuelve la matriz pero, si al número asignado no existe una solución devuelve error.

El problema viene cuando, al fallar la recursividad, la matriz base para seguir iterando entre los demás valores se modifica y debería quedar intacta a la situación inicial de buscar una posición para el número.

El código es el siguiente:

```
private static Result DLS(Problem_structure problem, int depth) {

        Problem_structure save = null, tree;
        Result result;

        int table[][] = problem.getTable();
        int magicNum = problem.getMagicNum();
        int rowCounter[] = problem.getRowCounter();
        int colCounter[] = problem.getColCounter();
        int diagCounter = problem.getDiagCounter();
        int availableNum[] = problem.getAvailableNum();

        if(depth < 0){
            result = new Result(-1, table);
            return result;
        }
```

El inicio en la recursividad aparece cuando encuentra una posición y un número libre y lo intento asignar a una clase nueva:

```
tree =  new Problem_structure(table, magicNum, rowCounter, colCounter, diagCounter, availableNum);
                            result = DLS(tree, depth-1);
```

la función devuelve un -1 y la matriz incompleta en caso de fallo o 0 y la matriz resultado en caso correcto.

En caso de fallo intento reasignar los valores originales, pero el programa realiza las operaciones sobre la matriz obtenida de la recursividad:

```
int retTable[][] = result.getTable();
                            System.out.println("Returned Table: ");
                            for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
                                System.out.print("|");
                                for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++){
                                    System.out.print(retTable[i][j] + "\t");
                                }
                                System.out.println("|");
                            }

                            int error = result.getFinish();
                            if(error == 0){
                                System.out.println("Table found");
                                return result;
                            }

                            //Reset values in case of fail
                            if(depth > 0) {
                                table = save.getTable();
                                rowCounter = save.getRowCounter();
                                colCounter = save.getColCounter();
                                diagCounter = save.getDiagCounter();
                                availableNum = save.getAvailableNum();
                            }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En donde esta la funcion recursiva que falla?

Comment: Hola Jose, probablemente quieres utilizar una copia de la matriz y no la misma copia para iniciar la recursion. Cuando asignas variables en java estas solo asignando una referencia a la misma, no copiandola.

Comment: Disculpad haber insertado todo el codigo de golpe, como podeis ver soy algo nuevo. Pero sí como se refiere Klaimmore, quiero trabajar con una copia de la matriz y no con la misma al igual que diferentes arrays de control que lleva el rpograma. El problema viene en que al intentar guardar esa copia, el programa escribe sobre la original

Answer (score 0):

Las constantes pueden recibir un valor a lo largo del programa. Pueden nacer sin valor, y luego recibir un valor más adelante, por supuesto siempre antes de poder trabajar con ellas. Y una vez que una constante ha recibido ese valor, ese valor ya no cambiará nunca más.

Si lo que quieres por otro lado es que si pueda cambiar, pero que después en algún punto del programa vuelva a sus valores iniciales, lo que yo haría sería construir un método que devuelva una matriz con esos valores. Así puedes acudir a ese método en cualquier momento.

Incluso, si lo que quieres es tener una matriz que algunos valores puedan cambiar a lo largo del código y otros que no puedan cambiar nunca, también ese método puede lograrlo. En vez de asignar un valor, asigna una constante con ese valor a la posición de la matriz.

Y por último, si lo que quieres es resetear a su valor inicial única y exclusivamente posiciones concretas, también podrías lograrlo mediante un método distinto. El cual podría tener el mismo nombre si quisieras, pero que recibiera parámetros distintos al primero.